# generics casting - it's not able to cast from GClass<string> to GClass<T>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I've a class:

```
public class GClass<T>
{
     private T data;
     //...
}
```

Then I've a function returning a GClass like:

```
public GClass<T> dialog<T>(String to)
{
    GClass<T> result = null;
    switch (to)
    {
        case "x":
            result = (GClass<T>)this.dialogX();  <<<<<<<<<<<<
            break;
        case "y":
            result = (GClass<T>)this.dialogY();  <<<<<<<<<<<<
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then `dialogX` and `dialogY` look like:

```
private GClass<string> dialogX()
{
    //...
}
```

Compiler is telling me that it's not able to convert a `GClass<string>` to `GClass<T>` in lines marked as `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576770/casting-a-string-to-a-generic?rq=1) I should be able to do that:

```
result = (GClass<T>)(GClass<object>)this.dialogX();
```

Comment: How do you expect it to convert `GClass<string>` to a `GClass<T>`?

Comment: Sorry, a copy miswriting... I've edited the code. Yes the question is I want to cast from GClass<string> to GClass<T>.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but a 'string' is not a 'T' hence the compiler's complaint.

Comment: Aren't you able to call `dialog<string>`? And then cast the `GClass<string>` object returned by `dialogX` to `GClass<string>`? I've seen a lumps of third party code using functions like `T function<T>(...)`

Comment: Obviously, I'm goint to call it using several generic concrete options.

Comment: What about this[1] [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576770/casting-a-string-to-a-generic?rq=1

Comment: Will the output of your `dialog` function always result in a `GClass<string>`, like your current code shows?  Or will your `case` statement return different `GClass` instances of different types depending on the `String to` parameter?  Maybe if you expand your example a little bit, it will help clarify your intent.  Currently, I don't see any reason why `dialog`'s return type shouldn't simply be `GClass<string>` instead of `GClass<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, i don't know all code and your needs, but how about just use As operator

```
switch (to)
    {
        case "x":
            result = this.dialogX() as GClass<T>;
            break;
        case "y":
            result = this.dialogY() as GClass<T>;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: It's worked! What's the difference between `(GClass<T>)this.dialogX()` and `this.dialogX() as GClass<T>`?

Comment: Msdn give more detailed answer. In your case operator As not throw error in IDE because cast will applied in runtime. But beware, if cast fail, method  return NULL. Sorry for my english